# MySQL - Group and total, but return all rows in each group

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query that finds each time the same person occurs in my table between a specific date range.  It then groups this person and totals their spending for a specific range.  If their spending habits are greater than X amount, then return each and every row for this person between date range specified. Not just the grouped total amount.  This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT member_id, 
SUM(amount) AS total 
FROM `sold_items` 
GROUP BY member_id 
HAVING total > 50
```

This is retrieving the correct total and returning members spending over $50, but not each and every row. Just the total for each member and their grand total.  I'm currently querying the whole table, I didn't add in the date ranges yet.

Comment: Not possible. When you `group`, all member rows of that group are collapsed down into a single representative row.  If you want the original member rows, then you can't use `group by`.

Comment: Agree.  This is where you want to have an application layer over the query to provide subtotals and breakdowns as required by the report.

Comment: You can `JOIN` this subquery with the original table to return all of the relevant rows.

Comment: I could achieve this result using the OVER() function in SQL Server, not sure if there is anything similar in mySQL.

Comment: I'm writing my back-end in PHP.  I was considering returning the members over X amount back to my PHP Model and then run a 2nd query using IN and just writing a loop to include all members that were found in the first query.  Is this poor practice?

Comment: @Barmar I was attempting to use JOIN to accomplish this, but I kept breaking my query.  Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`JOIN` this subquery with the original table:

```
SELECT si1.*
FROM sold_items AS si1
JOIN (SELECT member_id
      FROM sold_items
      GROUP BY member_id
      HAVING SUM(amount) > 50) AS si2
ON si1.member_id = si2.member_id
```

The general rule is that the subquery groups by the same column(s) that it's selecting, and then you join that with the original query using the same columns.

Comment: This appears to have fixed my issue!  Thanks!  And I never knew I could write a nested select statement like that with a JOIN.  Pretty awesome.

Comment: It doesn't work , it doesn't return all resutls for me : http://pastebin.com/DhvrmNsq The query should return duplicate results (same device and same time) but it misses the duplicates of more than 2 instances.

Comment: Your subquery is not correct. It just selects one of the IDs from each group, not all the IDs. You need to select the same columns you're grouping on, and then use those columns in the join.

Comment: @singe3 You shouldn't downvote when the reason is because you did your version wrong.

Comment: Alright, thanks for explaining, sorry for the downvote :)

Comment: @singe3 I've edited the question so you can now change your vote.

Comment: Add `DISTINCT` to the first `SELECT` to remove duplicates

Comment: @alexpirine The question says to retrieve "each and every row" for the selected users. Why would you want to remove duplicates? And if the table has a unique key, there won't be any duplicates.

Comment: For some reason I had duplicates, intuitively I would say it's related to the `JOIN`.

Comment: @alexpirine The subquery in the join only has 1 row per `member_id`, because of `GROUP BY`. So it can't create duplicates.

Comment: Solution works for SQL Server as well and will not cause any Syntax Issues

Comment: Only works if you group by exactly one identifier. In my case I need to group by two columns

Comment: @MarianKlühspies I don't see why it wouldn't work for multiple columns. Just use both columns in the `GROUP BY` and `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: If you can't get it working, write a new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT member_id, amount
FROM sold_items si
INNER JOIN (SELECT member_id, 
SUM(amount) AS total 
FROM `sold_items` 
GROUP BY member_id 
HAVING total > 50) spenders USING (member_id)
```

The query you have already built can be used as a temporary table to join with. if member_id is not an index on the table, this will become slow with scale.
The word spenders is a table alias, you can use any valid alias in its stead.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few syntaxes that will get the result you are looking, here is one using an inner join to ensure that all rows returned have a member_id in the list returned by the group by and that the total is repeated for each a certain member has:

```
SELECT si.*, gb.total from sold_items as si, (SELECT member_id as mid, 
SUM(amount) AS total 
FROM `sold_items` 
GROUP BY member_id 
HAVING total > 50) as gb where gb.mid=si.member_id;
```

Comment: Please don't use implicit joins in answers. We try to promote ANSI joins.

Comment: My apologies, makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this might help:

```
SELECT 
    member_id, 
    SUM(amount) AS amount_value,
    'TOTAL' as amount_type
FROM 
    `sold_items` 
GROUP BY 
    member_id 
HAVING 
    SUM(amount) > 50

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    member_id,
    amount AS amount_value,
    'DETAILED' as amount_type
FROM 
    `sold_items` 
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            A.member_id, 
            SUM(amount) AS total 
        FROM 
            `sold_items` A 
        GROUP BY 
            member_id 
        HAVING 
            total <= 50
    ) AS A
    ON `sold_items`.member_id = A.member_id
```

Results of the above query should be like the following:

```
member_id     amount_value    amount_type
==========================================
1             55              TOTAL
2             10              DETAILED
2             15              DETAILED
2             10              DETAILED
```

so the column `amount_type` would distinguish the two specific member groups

Answer (score 0):

You could do subquery with `EXISTS` as an alternative:

```
select *
from sold_items t1
where exists (
    select * from sold_items t2
    where t1.member_id=t2.member_id
    group by member_id
    having sum(amount)>50
)
```

ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to **group by multiple columns**, you can use a **composite identifier** with **concatenate** in combination with a group by subquery

```
select id, key, language, group
  from translation

  --query all key-language entries by composite identifier...
  where concat(key, '_', language) in (

    --by lookup of all key-language combinations...
    select concat(key, '_', language)
    from translation
    group by key, language
    
    --that occur more than once
    having count(*) > 1

  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL version 8 (or newer), do sum over partition:

```
select member_id, amount, total
from
(
    SELECT member_id, amount, SUM(amount) over (partition by member_id) AS total 
    FROM `sold_items` 
) s
where total > 50
```