# Group by 2 columns with 2 joins and return all rows with totals

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have 3 tables which I need to query where I need to group by 2 columns and also join the tables but still return all results.

```
Users
ID User_name Category Reason Change_date
1  John      1        2      2016-01-05
2  James     3        1      2015-10-02
3  Peter     1        4      2016-01-04
4  Tony      1        4      2016-01-15
5  Fred      1        4      2016-02-25
6  Rick      3        2      2016-04-19
7  Sonia     2        1      2016-10-14
8  Michelle  2        2      2015-11-09
9  Phillip   3        3      2016-03-01
10 Simon     3        3      2016-03-07

Category
ID Category_name
1  User
2  Super user
3  Admin

Reason
ID Reason_name
1  Promotion
2  Upgrade
3  Sponsor
4  Normal
```

I did some searching and found https://stackoverflow.com/a/28158276/1278201 and modified my query to try and use it:

```
SELECT category_name, reasons.reason_name, u1.id as user_id, user_name 
from users as u1
JOIN (SELECT id from users where users.change_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' 
AND '2016-11-06' group by users.category, users.reason) AS u2
ON u1.id = u2.id
left join reason on u1.reason=category.id 
left join category on u1.category=category.id
```

The results being returned are only using the group by - I should have 8 rows returned but I am only getting 5 which is one for each occurrence of each reason within each category.

My expected outcome is:

```
category_name reason_name           user_id user_name
User          Upgrade               1       John
                                                                  "Upgrade" count       1
              Normal                3       Peter
                                    4       Tony
                                    5       Fred
                                                                  "Normal" count        3
                                                                  "User" count          4 
Super user    Promotion             7       Sonia
                                                                  "Promotion" count     1
                                                                  "Super user" count    1 
Admin         Upgrade               6       Rick
                                                                  "Upgrade" count       1
              Sponsor               9       Phillip
                                    10      Simon
                                                                  "Sponsor" count       2
                                                                  "Admin" count         3
```

How can I get all 8 rows returned as well as being able to get counts for each `category_name` and `reason_name`?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `u2`?

Comment: I modified my original query using the answer I linked to - I think the idea is you join on itself in effect to allow you to then view all data rather than just the grouped results

Comment: Don't use `GROUP BY` in the subquery. You're picking one random user from each group.

Comment: In the answer you linked to, it's grouping by the same column it returns. What you're doing doesn't require any grouping.

Comment: If I don't use grouping how can I then go on to get a total for 'User' for example? I will need to be able to show the total for each category_name and also then the total for each reason_name under each category_name

Comment: I don't see a total in your expected output, just a list of users.

Comment: Now you are closer to tell us what you are after :-)

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't gotten to that point yet - I knew I needed to get all rows returned first which I was not able to do hence why I didn't include that. I do need all rows displayed and also totals which is my next step after I figure out how to get all the rows

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `GROUP BY` in the subquery, because then it only returns one user ID from each group.

In fact, you don't need the subquery at all. You can just use a `WHERE` clause to select users that meet the `change_date` criteria.

```
SELECT category_name, reasons.reason_name, u1.id as user_id, user_name 
from users as u1
left join reason on u1.reason=category.id 
left join category on u1.category=category.id 
where u1.change_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-11-06'
```

To get subtotals of the groupings by category and reason, you can use `GROUP BY` and `WITH ROLLUP`.

```
SELECT category_name, reasons.reason_name, u1.id as user_id, user_name, COUNT(*) AS total
from users as u1
left join reason on u1.reason=category.id 
left join category on u1.category=category.id 
where u1.change_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-11-06'
GROUP BY category_name, reason_name, user_id WITH ROLLUP
```

In the script that displays the results, the totals are in the rows where `user_id` is `NULL`. The category totals also have `reason IS NULL`. So you can display these rows appropriately in the script that displays the results. If you really need to do it all in MySQL, you can put the above query in a subquery, and the containing query can test for `user_id IS NULL` and `reason_name IS NULL`.

Comment: Apologies, this does give me all the rows and this is more or less what I had originally - the group by was added so I could get totals by category and reason

Comment: Get totals in a separate query, like `SELECT category, reason, COUNT(*) as total from users GROUP BY category, reason`. Then join this with the other tables.

Comment: Ah OK, that makes sense! Do I need to join twice to get the individual totals?

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what you need to do, since you haven't shown the result you're trying to achieve. I don't see where totals would fit into the result you show.

Comment: You haven't even said what you're trying to total? There are no columns with amounts to add together. Do you mean counts?

Comment: Yes sorry, counts - not totals. Not slept in 48 hours and it catching up with me :/

Comment: If you update the question to show what you're really trying to accomplish, I can update the answer to show how to combine them.

Comment: Have changed the question to show the counts included in the output

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you can do totals in the same query using `WITH ROLLUP`.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are looking for in the expected output, this might be what you looking for:

```
SELECT
Category_name, reason_name, users.ID,User_name
FROM
  Users 
  inner join Category on Category.ID=Users.Category
  inner join Reason on Reason.ID=Users.Reason
where users.change_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-11-06'
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9fe6f1/3)