# Another SQL Show all records in a Group By, with a HAVING

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

We accidentally let in some duplicate clients

| id | Lookup |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | abc |
| 3 | def |
| 4 | def |
| 5 | ghi |
| 6 | ghi |
| 7 | j |
| 8 | k |
| 9 | l |

I have a query that shows the duplicate Lookup values

```
SELECT Lookup, COUNT (Lookup)
  FROM Clients
  GROUP BY Lookup
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

That produces

| Lookup | (No name) |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 2 |
| def | 2 |
| ghi | 2 |

I'd like to see the id numbers next to those.

| id | Lookup |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | abc |
| 3 | def |
| 4 | def |
| 5 | ghi |
| 6 | ghi |

I found [MySQL - Group and total, but return all rows in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158083/mysql-group-and-total-but-return-all-rows-in-each-group) which looks very close to what I'm doing.  But:

```
  SELECT a.id, a.Lookup
  FROM Clients as a
  JOIN (SELECT id, Lookup
  FROM Clients
  GROUP BY Lookup, id
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as b
  ON a.id = b.id
```

Produces an empty result set.  (I tried with and without the Lookup in "JOIN (SELECT id, Lookup").

That looks to me like it should work.  What am I overlooking?

Comment: If you want to mimic that structure, then your join should change to... `...JOIN (SELECT Lookup FROM Clients GROUP BY Lookup HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as b ON a.lookup = b.lookup`. T

Comment: your sub-select is grouping by `id` as well as `Lookup`, and `id` is unique, so there are no results where `COUNT(*) > 1`, so there is nothing to join to

Comment: Danny, of course.  Obvious, once you point it out.

Isolated, thanks.  That worked.  And, it sidesteps my mistake that Danny pointed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join it on the `Lookup` instead of `id`

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Clients c
JOIN (
    SELECT Lookup, COUNT (Lookup)
    FROM Clients
    GROUP BY Lookup
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) cnt ON cnt.Lookup = c.Lookup
```

Answer (score 3):

Do a count over partition to get count for each lookup value:

```
select *
from (
  select id, lookup, count(*) over (partition by lookup) cnt
  from clients
) c
where cnt > 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/7FfLZUIf

Comment: Thanks, this does work.  But, Isolated's version, in the comments up above, is a little more verbose, but feels a little simpler, to me.  I'm still a near-noob in SQL.

Comment: @Mighty That version is probably going to be slower than this one, which only uses a single scan of the base table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a straightforward subquery and an IN clause.

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM Clients
 WHERE Lookup IN (SELECT Lookup 
                    FROM Clients
                   GROUP BY Lookup
                   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )
```